# Searching through text file and randomly choosing?

Tags: java, text, random

my homework is this if more context is needed - I would explain it but it is pretty long to explain and the text files are provided on the site if people need to look at them: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis110/hw/hw06/index.html

Right now I am on Step 2 and stuck on randomly choosing from the three items associated with the treasure class, checking to see if they start with "tc". I can extract the treasure class from the monster.txt file and I have the monster. This is my method for finding the treasure class:

```
public static void getTreasureClass(Monster monGet)
    throws FileNotFoundException{
    Random rand = new Random();
    String tc=monGet.getTreasureClass();
    Scanner file=new Scanner(new File ("TreasureClassEx.txt"));
    System.out.println(tc);
    while(!file.next().equals(tc)){
        file.next();
        }
    tc=file.next();
    if (tc.startsWith("tc:")){

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("test");
        }   
    }
```

It is extremely incomplete, but I would appreciate some tips on where to go next in terms of randomly choosing from the three items, or if my code is bad. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a 'Hell_Bovine' has a Treasure Class of "tc:Cow_(H)".

So you're looking for this line in TreasureClassEx.txt

```
tc:Cow_(H)  tc:Act_5_(H)_Equip_B    tc:armo3    tc:armo3
```

Then you'll choose one of the three options at random.

And you'll keep reading the TreasureClassEx, finding the right line, and making a random choice for as long as the "treasure class" that you're looking for starts with "tc:".

For example, for "tc:Cow_(H)" you might choose "tc:armo3".  For "tc:armo3", you might choose "Quilted_Armor".  And then you would stop there.

*At least that's how **I'm** reading the instructions.*   ;->

Answer (score 0):

Makes sure that you import the things that I add, because you dont show imports i will not add them

```
public static void getTreasureClass(Monster monGet)
    throws FileNotFoundException{
    Random rand = new Random();
    String tc=monGet.getTreasureClass();
    Scanner file=new Scanner(new File ("TreasureClassEx.txt"));
    System.out.println(tc);
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    while(!file.next().equals(tc)){
        file.next();
        }
    tc=file.next();
    if (tc.startsWith("tc:")){
    list.add(tc);
    }

    String treasure = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
    else {
        System.out.println("test");
        }   
    }
```

So in this I saved the example in the String value 'treasure'

I dont feel good helping you with your homework -_-

Comment: Thanks, we haven't covered linked lists in class yet but I do appreciate the help. Also I'm confused about where you put String treasure=list.get... . Since it's between the if and the else, does it run if tc starts with tc or does it run otherwise? Or is it independent of the if/else loop? Thanks!

Comment: It is independent of the if/else statement, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Looking at the instructions, I do not think that selecting a random LINE is correct.  Looks like the randomness is within lines.